# grep - Get word from string

Tags: grep

I have a bunch of strings that I have to fetch the 'port_num' from -

```
"76 : client=new; tags=circ, LINK; port_num=switch01; far_port=Gi1/0"
```

The word might be in a different place in the string and it might be a different length, but it always says 'port_num=' before it and ';' after it...

I only want this bit- 'switch01'

Currently I use-

```
| grep -Eo 'port_num=.+' | cut -d"=" -f2 | cut -d";" -f1'
```

But there has got to be a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `grep -oP '(?<=port_num=).+(?=;)'`, if you run this:

```
echo "76 : client=new; tags=circ, LINK; port_num=switch01; far_port=Gi1/0" \
| grep -oP '(?<=port_num=).+(?=;)'
```

result will be:

```
switch01
```

Updated answer: `grep -oP '(?<=port_num=)[^;]+(?=;)'`

Comment: Spoke to soon! sometimes there is a second ';' after the first... and it seems to continue until the last ';' in the line - any ideas?

Comment: `grep -oP '(?<=port_num=)[^;]+(?=;)'`

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would use:

```
... | grep -E 'port_num=.+' | sed 's/^.*port_num=\([^;]*\).*$/\1/'
```

This works with or without the `-o` on `grep`, and the availability of `-P` will depend on the version of `grep` you have.  (e.g., my `grep` does not have it).  I'm not saying the other answers that rely on `-P` aren't any good -- they look fine to me.  But `grep -P` will be less portable.

IMHO, piping `grep` with `sed` allows each utility to do what it specializes in -- `grep` is for selecting lines, `sed` is for modifying lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
... | grep -Po 'port_num.+(?=;)'
```

This uses `grep`'s Perl Compatible Regular Expression (PCRE) syntax.  The `(?=;)` is a look-ahead assertion which looks for a match with ";" but doesn't include it in the matched output.

This produces:
    port_num=switch01

As @Vladimir Kovpak noted, if you want to exclude the "port_num=" string from this output, add a look-behind assertion:

```
... | grep -Po '(?<=port_num).+(?=;)'
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in a simple `sed` command:

```
s="76 : client=new; tags=circ, LINK; port_num=switch01; far_port=Gi1/0"
sed 's/.*port_num=\([^;]*\);.*/\1/' <<< "$s"
```

```
switch01
```